# JavaScript - rock, paper, scissors - user input is not acknowledged

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

i recently started learning JavaScript and been working on the final assignment for the class where we have to create a "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game. While i did manage to solve the same type of a game at codecademy.com - it was mostly with the help of several If Statements and 1 function. However, for this assignment we're required to use functions, arrays and loops, while keeping a score of each player's progress, notifying the user of the updated scores, as well providing the chance to exit the game at any time... here's the detailed explanation of what's required for this assignment:

> Write a Rock, Paper, Scissors game. Your task is to create the logic
>   for a Rock, Paper Scissors game. The game will welcome a user and then
>   prompt the user for their first round of play by asking them to type
>   rock, paper or scissors Each round will have the following steps:
>
> 1. The user will be prompted to type, rock, paper, scissors OR exit
> 2. The computer will randomly pick either rock, paper or scissors
>          and alert the user to this choice
> 3. A winner will be declared and a point will be awarded to the winner.
> 4. The user will be alerted of the running score for both themselves and the computer.
> 5. The round will be repeated
>
> You are to evaluate whether or not the user wins, loses or ties the
>   round, based on the rules here:
>   http://www.rinkworks.com/games/rps.shtml The game should have an
>   infinite number of rounds, until the user types exit in the game
>   prompt. If the user types the word exit into a prompt, let the user
>   know who won the game and the final score. I will ultimately leave the
>   architecture of the program up to you, but do require that: ￼You will
>   need to incorporate conditionals, loops, arrays and make use of
>   function calls and ￼comments to create this program.
>   - the computer creates a new random choice between rock, paper and scissors by calling a function you create to return either
>   “rock”,”paper”,”scissors”
>   - the logic for determining a winner of a round is contained inside a function you design to take both the user and computer’s choice as
>   parameters

I checked this in Chrome's console for errors and the problem that i'm having is that the code seems to work... only that it's the computer that's the only winner here... hence it seems as if the user input is completely ignored. Besides, if i hit the 'Cancel' button i get an error (according to Chrome's console) on line 20 telling me:

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

...I've originally added the following line of code for a reason, which is to make sure the user input matches all the lower-case options...

```
return userInput.toLowerCase();
```

When i removed the .toLowerCase() method only to simply return the userInput (and then ran the code in Chrome's console again), i got stuck in an infinite loop...

Here's my entire code:

```js
var choice1Score = 1;
var choice2Score = 1;

function compChoice() {
 var choiceArr = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; 
 var random = choiceArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
 return random;
}

function userChoice(){
 var userInput = prompt("Please enter your choice of either rock, paper or scissors. To exit, hit the 'Cancel' button.");
 return userInput.toLowerCase();
}


while (userChoice != "Cancel") {

    function scoring(choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie.";
        } if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice1 === "scissors") {
                return "Rock wins. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
            } else {
                return "Paper wins. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
            }
        } if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice1 === "rock") {
                return "Paper wins. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
            } else {
                return "Scissors win. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
            }
        } if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice1 === "paper") {
                return "Scissors win. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
            } else {
                return "Rock wins. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(scoring(userChoice(), compChoice()));

}
```

Any help, suggestions and comments will be much appreciated!

Comment: for the crash on cancel, prompt return null to signify that the user entered nothing. you will need a special case for that

Comment: One problem I can see immediately is that in your `while` loop you're comparing the string `cancel` to the `function` *itself*, as opposed to the function's result. That's the difference between `while (func != "cancel")` and `while (func() != "cancel")` - the former will always equate to false

Comment: You're script doesn't satisfy the first step: "The user will be prompted to type, rock, paper, scissors **OR exit**"

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that your while loop is checking if "Cancel" not "cancel" is entered? If you take the lower case of "caNCel" it will never equal "Cancel". I also notice that userChoice, the variable, isn't set or defined anywhere. Assuming what you've provided is your entire code, you need to think through how to handle this (HINT: you should call userChoice() only once for each round; since you need to do multiple checks, did they enter cancel or who won, you'll need to store it to a variable first).

Also, I think you mean for the nested if statements to check against choice2.

Might I suggest you look into learning how to use the Chrome console to debug using breakpoints so that you can look at the value of variables at each instruction as Chrome executes the the program line by line? These are both issues you would have easily caught had you looked at the exact values Chrome was using.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the issues here is you aren't comparing the two choices other than in the tie case. For example:

```
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        return "Rock wins. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
    } 
    else {
        return "Paper wins. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
}
```

The second line should be `if (choice2 === "scissors") {`

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the "Cancel" button, `prompt()` returns `null`, so `userInput` is null, resulting in the error. Instead of checking if the user's choice equals `"Cancel"`, check if `userInput` is `null`. If it is, stop the game.

Also, in `scoring`, you have three typos where you type `choice1` for the computer's choice. Remember that the computer's choice is `choice2` as you passed them in, not `choice1`.

Furthermore, don't put `scoring()` inside your `while` loop because then, `scoring()` is re-created over and over again each time the player plays the game. This is much less efficient than just creating it once by putting it on the outside.

```js
var choice1Score = 1;
var choice2Score = 1;

function compChoice() {
 var choiceArr = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; 
 var random = choiceArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
 return random;
}

function userChoice(){
 var userInput = prompt("Please enter your choice of either rock, paper or scissors. To exit, hit the 'Cancel' button.");
 //If userInput is null, return null:
 if (userInput == null) return null;
 //Otherwise, return the lowercase version of userInput:
 return userInput.toLowerCase();
}

function scoring(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie.";
    } if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "Rock wins. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
        } else {
            return "Paper wins. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
        }
    } if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "Paper wins. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
        } else {
            return "Scissors win. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
        }
    } if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "Scissors win. Your score is: " + choice1Score++;
        } else {
            return "Rock wins. The computer's score is: " + choice2Score++;
        }
    }
}

//Keep looping infinitely:
while (true) {
    //Get the user's choice:
    var curUserChoice = userChoice();
    //If the user's choice is clicking the "Cancel" button, exit:
    if (curUserChoice == null) break;
    //Otherwise, play the game and alert the user:
    alert(scoring(curUserChoice, compChoice()));
}
```

Comment: Why you've moved the definition of `scoring()`? And you've changed the rules (see step 1: "...**exit** ")

Comment: Don't put a function inside a `while` loop. Also, I didn't really change the rules; I just implemented it the way it seemed that you wanted it. I made it so that the user can exit by clicking the "Cancel" button.

Comment: Also, the reason you shouldn't put a function inside a `while` loop unless you really have to is because that function gets recreated each time you pass through the `while` loop which is much less efficient than just creating it once by putting it on the outside.

Comment: I just wanted you to elaborate the fact why you've moved the definition of `scoring()` to give @Netz an explanation as he's a beginner ;)

Comment: Ah...OK. I put the explanation of why `scoring()` should be declared outside the `while` loop inside of my answer. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
  values = {
  'Paper' : {
               'Paper'   : 'Ties with'
               'Rock'    : 'Beats'
               'Scissors': 'Loses to'
             }
  'Rock' :  {
               'Paper'   : 'Loses to'
               'Rock'    : 'Ties with'
               'Scissors': 'Beats'
             }
  'Scissors' : {
                 'Paper'   : 'Beats'
                 'Rock'    : 'Loses to'
                 'Scissors': 'Ties with'
                }
  }
  a = prompt("First sign?\n")
  b = prompt("Second sign?\n")
  console.log(a, values[a][b], b, "!")
```

**How it works**

```
> First sign?
> Paper      <-- This is input
> Second sign?
> Rock       <-- This is input
> Paper Beats Rock!
```

Comment: Note that in the question it was for an assignment where there were requirements to use functions, arrays, and loops and that they had to keep score and offer a way to exit.

Comment: This is just a base for whatever they want to do, related to rock, paper, scissors

Answer (score -4):

First off, change this:
`while (userChoice != "Cancel")`

To:
`while(userChoice != "cancel")`

Comment: Did you read the requirement? "The game should have **an infinite number of rounds**, until the user types exit in the game prompt"

Comment: `userChoice` is not even called. it should be `userChoice()` also. it will be an inifite loop because of the `toLowerCase()` comparing to Cancel (notice the capital C)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Yea, I was going to add more but then after it got dowvoted -10 I didn't bother adding more.